# Execute code at fixed interval of time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, nstimeinterval

I want to execute my code at fixed interval of time(suppose at 6PM daily) whether my app is running in background or not though my iOS app automatically.

Please suggest how can I do this.

Comment: I am not sure but you can achieve this by silent push notification. when it arrives you can execute the code.

Comment: Integrate silent push notification in application with the help of backend, it will not show popup but make your app live in background and from there you can perform actions which you want to perform.

Comment: watch - making energy efficient code in wwdc 2015

Comment: Is there any other alternative of executing code as I dont want to send notification?